# Help to find all the solution of below equation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis

$$(1+\frac{x}{1}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+...)=(1+\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+...)^x$$
Obviously $x=0$ is one solution , and it seems to l.h.s equal to $e^x$ and r.h.s equals to $(e)^x$
Now is there $x\in \mathbb{R} ?$ or ..This is incorrect solution ?
   I do appreciate if you light a lamp on this situation.

Comment: $e^x=e^x$ for all $x$ no matter which set $x$ is based from.

Comment: The relation holds for all $x\in\mathbb {C} $ but neither the proof is obvious nor easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that

$$e^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$$

Thus the left-hand-side of your equality is $e^x$. The parenthetical in the right-hand-side is $e$ (take $x=1$ in the series above).

Thus the statement becomes

$$e^x = e^x$$

which is trivially true for any $x$ on which the exponential is well-defined. For example, this works for all $x \in \Bbb R$ or $x \in \Bbb C$. Without know specifically the domain you're working in, it's hard to say for sure what exactly you're looking for $x$ to be in.

Comment: Well the equality in question is not trivially true but rather demands a proof which is not easy.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh How do you reckon? Maybe I'm overlooking some obvious detail.

Comment: Let the Left Hand Side of the equality in question be $f(x) $. Then using multiplication of infinite series one can show that $f(x+y) =f(x) f(y) $ for all complex $x, y$. Armed with this and a little algebra one proves that $f(x) =\{f(1) \}^x $ for rational $x$. The case of irrational and complex $x$ requires some definition of irrational/complex exponents and then one needs to show that the equality holds based on that definition. Depending on definition the proofs vary in difficulty.

Comment: The use of notation $e^x$ for left side gives the impression that it satisfies the exponential property automatically / obviously.

Comment: So the overall issue seems to be that, essentially, we're assuming the result we trying to prove?

Comment: In a sense yes. I think you should mention that the series in start of your answer satisfies exponential property (via Cauchy product of series).